# Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Student' operator

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

This is the code I have:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(sConn))
        {
            sc.Open();


            string SearchFor = txtSearch.Text;



            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                grdData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Concat("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Forename LIKE '%", SearchFor, "%'");
            }
```

When I run the code I get:

> "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Student' operator."

I'm using WPF... I want it so I can search for people by just typing a letter of their name what can I do?

Comment: @SonerGönül It's what ever I type within the text box, so a letter of a person's name from my database

Comment: -1, please Understand properly for which exact requirement  RowFilter is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill your `DataTable` first with some data and then you can filter results

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(sConn))
{
   sc.Open();
   using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
   {
       adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", sc);
       var dataset = new DataSet();
       adapter.Fill(dataset);
       var dt = dataset.Tables[0];
       var dv = dt.DefaultView;
       dv.RowFilter = String.Concat("[Forename] LIKE '%", SearchFor, "%'");
       grdData.ItemsSource = dv;
   }
}
```

or filter in SQL without `RowFilter`

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Forename LIKE @forename", sc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", String.Concat("%", SearchFor, "%"));
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your filter, you only need to specify the [WHERE clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx), it's not a full SQL SELECT statement that is needed. So it should look like this:

```
grdData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Concat("Forename LIKE '%", SearchFor, "%'");
```

Be aware though, that a user could enter some characters like `%`, `'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

please change as  below..

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter ="Forename LIKE '%" + SearchFor + "%'"
```

Comment: I'm now getting "Cannot find column [Forename]."

Comment: for specifying filter condition. your column must be a part of your datatable. Otherwise on which condition data will get selected. So would suggest dt must contain ForeName Column

Answer (score 0):

The "RowFilter" query is not a complete SQL query but rather a subset of a SQL query.
In your case you want something like:

```
grdData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[Forename] LIKE '%{0}%'", SearchFor);
```

For future reference: [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm now getting "Cannot find column [Forename]."

Comment: @BenNixon you need to have data inside the datatable before being able to filter the rows.