# Search code in vb.net for Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Hello Guys here is my code for search in text changed event.. Please help me, it gives an error of OPERAND MISSING AFTER ID. Can you tell me what is it? Thanks for your help.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
    If optName.Checked = True Then
        dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Student Name Like ' %{0}% '", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

    End If
    If optID.Checked = True Then
        dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Student ID Like ' %{0}% '", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778491/syntax-error-missing-operand-after-student-operator

Comment: if i type in the textbox. the records does not show any result... the Datagridview is empty...

Answer (score 0):

If those field names really contain spaces then you must wrap them in brackets:
[Student Name]
[Student ID]

Answer (score 0):

In your column names, `Student Name` and `Student ID`, you should wrap it around in brackets because it contains space.

For example: `[Student Name]`, `[Student ID]`